# How to get a bean from a dialog box using Strust2 and Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, struts2

I have a dialog box (called by another window) that contains a table. Every row in this table has the information of one "user" bean and a "Choose" button.

What i'm trying to do is that when the "Choose" button is clicked, the calling window receives the bean picked.

I'm using Struts2 and DOJO because i want that all this process being made via Ajax.

What should i do?